# Can I always write $Y=E[Y|X]+\varepsilon$ where $E[\varepsilon|X]=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose that we have two random variables $Y$ and $X$. Is it true that we can always write
$$
Y=E[Y|X]+\varepsilon
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is some random variable such that $E[\varepsilon|X]=0$? I think this is a basic projection result but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can always do this. Simply define $\varepsilon:=Y-E(Y\mid X)$. Then calculate
$$E(\varepsilon\mid X)=E(Y\mid X) - E(E(Y\mid X)\mid X)\stackrel{(*)}=E(Y\mid X) - E(Y\mid X)=0,$$
where in $(*)$ we use the fact that $E(Y\mid X)$ is already $\sigma(X)$-measurable.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. That was indeed very simple.

Comment: Of course this assumes $E(Y \mid X)$ exists.  It might not.  For example, take a random variable $Y$ where $E(Y)$ doesn't exist, and $X$ independent of $Y$.