# Can we always write $Z=E(Z|X)+E(Z|Y)+\varepsilon$ where $E(\varepsilon|X)=E(\varepsilon|Y)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose that we have the random variables $X,Y,Z$. Can we always decompose one of them (say $Z$) as
$$
Z=E(Z|X)+E(Z|Y)+\varepsilon
$$
where $E(\varepsilon|X)=E(\varepsilon|Y)=0$? (Suppose all expectations exist) This is true when we project on only one random variable ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782101/can-i-always-write-y-eyx-varepsilon-where-e-varepsilonx-0)). But the proof provided does not seem to work when we project on two random variables. I worry that there is a correlation term missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you could. Then, taking $E\left(\cdot|X\right)$ of both sides yields

$$E(Z|X) = E(Z|X) + E(E(Z|Y)|X) + E(\varepsilon|X).$$

The first term on the RHS is unchanged since $E(Z|X)$ is already measurable w.r.t. $X$. Then, you have

$$E(\varepsilon|X) = -E(E(Z|Y)|X)$$

but there is no reason why the RHS should be zero. $E(Z|Y)$ is a function of $Y$, but this may still have some arbitrary dependence on $X$.